# task scheduler in rdp run without login and show cmd

Tags: azure, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

I call a batch script in my taskscheduler. It opens the cmd when I select "Run only when user is logged on", but I don't see the window when I select "Run whether user is logged on or not.

Comment: I think you should post it on SU, not SO....

Answer (score 1):

There was a major security update for scheduled tasks in Vista and later. A task that runs logged on or not could be run at the Windows logon screen so there would be no user context and so no user interface. So task scheduler does not allow the task to display anything. It doesn't differentiate whether a user is actually logged on or not. That's why you don't see it running.

Since you had an Azure tag on your post I also included this part about scheduled tasks and networking:
You can also run into problems if your script tries to access mapped network drives or, for that matter, anything on the network.

Even with a supplied user name and password, task scheduler uses a different type of user authentication called "S4U" (Service-for-User) and S4U authentication does not allow network access at all.

All of this is good to prevent an intruder from running a scheduled task to access network resources when no one is logged on but requires you have a logged on user to run the task that accesses the network or the task must be run on the machine containing the data you want to access so it doesn't have to use the network.

More info here: [Task Security Context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: S4U logons (both Kerberos an MSV1_0) don't use a password, which is why they're limited to local system resources. They also require the right to do a batch logon, which administrators have, but standard users generally do not have. As to running when the user isn't logged on, that's running in the services session (0), which doesn't allow interactive desktop access. It's basically running as a service, and if you run it as the `LOCAL SERVICE` account, you can even use a service SID for the task to grant/deny access to securable objects.